# How to do git pull from remote when you are in another local branch?

Tags: git

I have two branches in local say A and B, I committed some changes in A as well as B. I push modifications of A to my remote brach say A. now i need pull from my remote branch to my local branch B . How can i do it?

Comment: Why can't you merge the changes from your local branch A to your local branch B?

Comment: @dotnetom :How do i merge two local branches.Im new to git .Plz help

Comment: Do you want to incorporate changes from the remote branch B to your local branch B or do you want to merge branch A to branch B ?

Comment: I need to get changes from branch A to my local branch B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> git checkout A
> git pull 
> git checkout B
> git rebase A
```

Will merge all the changes from local branch A(incorporating changes from the remote repository<sup>1</sup>) to local branch B.

1. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to `cherry-pick` your commits to branch B

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick HASHVALUE #Cherry pick all the commits one by one. (eg: HASHVALUE - 5e2ld9)
```

You can see the `HASHVALUE` of those commits from branch A by going to your remote from Web or inside branch A, type `git log --oneline`

Answer (score 0):

1. git checkout b (this will switch your branch to b)
2. git merge a (this will merge all changes from branch a into branch b)
3. git commit -a (this will commit your changes)

You can visit this link to further know about merging and branching.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging